# Как добавить multistage в dockerfile?

Tags: nginx, docker, dockerfile

Необходимо организовать multistage в контейнере. Сборка в одном контейнере запуск того что собрали в другом, как переделать докерфайл?

```
# get image from...
FROM debian:9 as builder
# maintainer
    LABEL maintainer="paffin"
#main dir
    WORKDIR /usr/local/src/
#Env versions
    ENV nginx_v="1.19.8" LuaJIT_v="2.0.5" ngx_v="0.3.0" lua_v="0.10.9rc7"
# updates
    RUN apt-get -y update && apt-get -y upgrade && apt-get install -y wget build-essential libpcre3 libpcre3-dev zlib1g zlib1g-dev
# modules
    RUN wget http://nginx.org/download/nginx-${nginx_v}.tar.gz && tar -zxvf nginx-${nginx_v}.tar.gz
    RUN wget http://luajit.org/download/LuaJIT-${LuaJIT_v}.tar.gz && tar -zxvf LuaJIT-${LuaJIT_v}.tar.gz
    RUN wget https://github.com/simpl/ngx_devel_kit/archive/v${ngx_v}.tar.gz && tar -zxvf v${ngx_v}.tar.gz 
    RUN wget https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module/archive/v${lua_v}.tar.gz  && tar -zxvf v${lua_v}.tar.gz

    RUN cd LuaJIT-${LuaJIT_v} && make -j2 && make install
    RUN cd nginx-${nginx_v} && export LUAJIT_LIB=/usr/local/lib && export LUAJIT_INC=/usr/local/LuaJIT/include/luajit-2.0 
    RUN cd nginx-${nginx_v} && ./configure --sbin-path=/usr/sbin/nginx \
    --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf \
    --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log \
    --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log \
    --user=nobody --group=nogroup \
    --prefix=/usr/local/nginx \
    --with-ld-opt='-Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/lib' \
    --add-module=/usr/local/src/lua-nginx-module-${lua_v} \
    --add-module=/usr/local/src/ngx_devel_kit-${ngx_v}
    RUN cd nginx-${nginx_v} && make && make install

FROM builder
    EXPOSE 80 22 443
    CMD [ "nginx", "-g", "daemon off;" ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Этот вопрос должен быть в разделе про docker.

Нужно собрать в builder'е результат в отдельную папку и уже её копировать в отдельный image.

Что-то вроде:

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1
FROM debian:9 as builder
WORKDIR /usr/local/src/
# сконфигурировать и собрать luajit и nginx на билд например в /usr/builder

FROM debian:9-slim
WORKDIR /usr/local
COPY --from=builder /usr/builder ./
EXPOSE 80 443
CMD [ "/usr/local/bin/nginx", "-g", "daemon off;" ]
```